# Invoke powershell script from java

Tags: java, powercli

I am trying to invoke some powercli script from Java and it fails.

**I am working with VMWare esx**

**This is my Java code:**

```
String command = "cmd.exe C:\\Users\\mayan\\Desktop\\scriptPS.ps1";
Process powerShellProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
powerShellProcess.getOutputStream().close();
```

**This is my script (.ps1 file):**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\Infrastructure\vSphere PowerCLI\vim.psc1
Get-VM -Name dev-maya | Get-NetworkAdapter | Set-NetworkAdapter -Connected:$false           
Get-VM -Name dev-maya | Get-NetworkAdapter | Set-NetworkAdapter -Connected:$true
```

Java invoke the first command and ignore the rest.

Does anyone have idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Do you load the module that contains `Get-VM` in your `ps1` file?

Comment: @alroc can you explain how to load the module that contains Get-VM in ps1 file? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\Infrastructure\vSphere PowerCLI\vim.psc1
```

with

```
Add-PSSnapin vmware.vimautomation.core
```

You'll also need to run `connect-viserver` as implied in the other answer.

Comment: noam, I have replaced the command according to your suggestion and now the first command (Connect-VIServer) is done, but the Get-VM commands do not execute, the program runs and nothing happens.

Comment: It works. I also add to the script the command $ConfirmPreference="none"  
that cancel the "are you sure?" question. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

please check your module first

```
get-module
```

if you do not have add Hyper-v module  then
you should have Hyper-v module for use get-vm

```
ipmo hyperv
```

for hypervisor vmware esxi you should see down link
[vmware esxi via powershell](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/windowstoolkit/wintk40u1/html/)
and for add

```
ipmo CimCmdlets
```

Comment: I get this error:

ipmo : The specified module 'hyperv' was not loaded because no valid module
file was found in any module directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ ipmo hyperv
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (hyperv:String) [Import-Mod
   ule], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comm
   ands.ImportModuleCommand

Comment: see this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846767.aspx) and this like for module [link](https://pshyperv.codeplex.com/)

Comment: sorry, ive been a little confused. I am working with VMWare esx and that is  why it did not worked well. i want to run this on powercli. i run this command in cmd:
 C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\Infrastructure\vSphere PowerCLI\vim.psc1
to open the prompt and then the commands Get-VM are working. but how it is possible for me to do it in Java?

Comment: @maya oops u should tell that is vmware esxi now see [link](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/windowstoolkit/wintk40u1/html/) and you should get module and import with `ipmo CimCmdlets`

Comment: It didn't solve the problem, but thanks. 
The problem is to invoke powercli commands from java when i'm using VMWare esx. Any other suggestions?

Comment: your first question about powershell not powercli sorry check [java](http://vijava.sourceforge.net/)